# What are the 128-bit to 512-bit registers used for?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, simd, cpu-registers

After looking at a table of registers in the x86/x64 architecture, I noticed that there's a whole section of 128, 256, and 512-bit registers that I've never seen them being used in assembly, or decompiled C/C++ code: XMM(0-15) for 128, YMM(0-15) for 256, ZMM(0-31) 512.

After doing a bit of digging what I've gathered is that you have to use 2 64-bit operations in order to perform math on a 128-bit number, instead of using generic `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` operations. If this is the case, then what exactly is the use of having these expanded register sets, and are there any assembly operations that you can use in order to manipulate them?

Comment: The wiki article you linked is broken EDIT: the problem is that there's a dot at the end of the URL.

Comment: Sorry. 2nd try: These registers are for the [Streaming SIMD Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are used in

- [Floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) operations
- Operations on [multiple pieces of data at once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (like in arrays, vectors or matrices)

Nowadays they're also commonly used for

- mass data movement/operation (like in `memcpy`) because they can copy a much larger amount of data in an iteration:

  - [Why are memcpy() and memmove() faster than pointer increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7776085/995714)
  - [Does rewriting memcpy/memcmp/... with SIMD instructions make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5321383/995714)
  - [faster alternative to memcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963898/995714)
  - [Why is memcpy() faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15724206/995714)
- string operations (to avoid iterating char-by-char):

  - [Can I use SIMD for speeding up string manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64975030/995714)
  - [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57650895/995714)
  - [Ridiculously fast string operations](https://arxiv.org/a/lemire_d_1.html)
  - [Parsing gigabytes of JSON per second](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson)

See also

- [Why is vectorization, faster in general, than loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35091979/995714)
- [Intel Publishes Blazing Fast AVX-512 Sorting Library, Numpy Switching To It For 10~17x Faster Sorts](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-AVX-512-Quicksort-Numpy)
- [What is "vectorization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1422149/995714)

---

> you have to use 2 64-bit operations in order to perform math on a 128-bit number

No, they're not meant for that purpose and you can't use them for 128-bit numbers *easily*. It's much much faster to add a 128-bit number with only 2 instructions: [`add rax, rbx; adc rdx, rcx`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27__int128+f(__int128+x,+__int128+y)%0A%7B%0A++++return+x+%2B+y%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.82709400697888,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dnative%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.17290599302112,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) instead of a ton of instructions if dealing with XMM registers. They may help in case of larger integers though. See

- [practical BigNum AVX/SSE possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27923192/995714)
- [Is it possible to use SSE and SSE2 to make a 128-bit wide integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200698/995714)

---

Regarding their applications, firstly they're used for **scalar floating-point operations**. So if you have `float` or `double` in C or C++ then they're most likely be stored in the low part of XMM registers and manipulated by instructions ending in `ss` (*scalar single*) or `sd` (*scalar double*)

In fact there is another set of eight 80-bit `ST(x)` registers which was available with the [x87 co-processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87) for doing floating-point math. However they're slow and less predictable. Slow because operations are done in higher precision by default, which inherently needs *more work* and also [requires a store then load to *round to lower precision*](https://yosefk.com/blog/consistency-how-to-defeat-the-purpose-of-ieee-floating-point.html) if necessary. Unpredictable is also because of the high precision. That might feel strange at first, but it's easy to explain, for example some operations overflow or underflow in `float` or `double` precision, but not in `long double` precision. That causes many bugs or unexpected results in 32 and 64-bit build<sup>1</sup>

[Here is a floating-point example on both sets of registers](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5ADMGqJgQDUMiHIXKAHqRXzFSgJ471%2BgF4BKDgAYAghwDsfW0pdLimAmJZLNAelNK/IYAVKYcAMxOdvYAItZ2tuiiAEYMmCoQSSKp6dpKWTmGOgVpShbxDlGubh5ePv6BvCFhkRWxFbbybPkppapdwD3ZpXkDQ4VGSmMl6eW2lfHV7p7E3n4BQQahEVEOcbZS5ozSAKxSpCzSVueo0gDC/EHCYhKN4bTnBFeHRwDWIFwTgA6E4ANnCAE5QbQrFD7LRwgAORHHKQAFnOAFs6FYrBdvqRblJzoIQHivlJrkc4LAkGhMQAHPBpMgUCD0pkslDMNj2XGkGTMgiYYikiDJAnJPAsJjEAzSD6kemYzAsAgAeRYDHllPOWExrGAaQJ%2BHcyAIeAAbphSbrSJhNJhkCJhQrztLhQwCQRiHhsVIPkceexHrxGHhkqTIEdUAyLagWLaALTqrhKJOY8JpjOy5AICIxBmqi0iTFcEmicSSWhB07nS52omaRGgpOgtFKZDBpT2IFWPtKCC4QgkN70JR3VCM5kisfmCehnifb7mI4ITBMLDESh/AFooFok6I%2BwncKg%2BxcaFcKz2VEY/GN6QksmkClU0g0xAoKeckXkSgcjO25doafJ4oKDDCqKlASnaUoynKbpKlOKpqpq2ompgBpsMadqmk6FrWra1z2o6zqugG7pqpgXp2j6fpukGhooIu4aRvAMZxngCbJuq4Tpga4j5uEMRoO45ZCJWEh0LWUhnA%2BJFNi2bYdiB3S9v2ViDsORDEGOOiTtOLJvFw84PLw/DLrqq6kOum4ijupD/ICQK0IitAQlCSLHuE9ighCKK0feDaKU%2BQgvm%2BhwfjAX6ASy/7sj%2BQHcqB/IQVBYqwSR8GyjqirKsW6E6iR%2BqGrhJV4GahE2gSDpOi6kiUeQ1G0SR9H%2BoGjDMZwFlhgwEZRhAnHxom0gpvxOZCQWMrVRWLzVrJ8khTc0jNq27adt2GkDkO%2BC6fpE5JcZ3DhOEZmLlZVK7lw%2B72BCJxcMiiJoh5Z5nneWI4niy2EmFpLkiuskST9RKXT8pDWqK3GXGiQA)

```
// f = x/z + y*z
x87:
        fld     dword ptr [esp + 12]
        fld     st(0)
        fdivr   dword ptr [esp + 4]
        fxch    st(1)
        fmul    dword ptr [esp + 8]
        faddp   st(1)
        ret
SSE:
        divss   xmm0, xmm2
        mulss   xmm1, xmm2
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
AVX:
        vdivss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vmulss  xmm1, xmm1, xmm2
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

The move to the faster and more consistent SSE registers is one of the reasons why [the 80-bit extended precision `long double` type is not available in MSVC anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120710/995714)

---

Then Intel introduced the [MMX instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_(instruction_set)) for [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) operations which uses the same `ST(x)` registers with the new name `MMX`. MMX might stand for *Multiple Math eXtension* or *Matrix Math eXtension*, but IMHO it's most likely or *MultiMedia eXtension*, since multimedia and the internet increasingly became important at the time. In multimedia solutions you very often have to do the same operations to each pixel, texel, sound sample... like these

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
   A[i] = B[i] + C[i];
   D[i] = E[i] * F[i];
}
```

Instead of operating on each element separately, we can speed up by doing multiple elements at a time. That's the reason people invented SIMD. With MMX you can increase the brightness of 8 pixel channels, or volume of four 16-bit sound samples at once... Operations on a single element is called [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(computing)), and the full register is called a vector, which is a set of scalar values

Due to MMX's drawbacks (like the reuse of `ST` registers, or the lack of floating-point support), when extended the SIMD instruction set with [Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) Intel decided to give them a *completely new set of registers* named XMM which is twice longer (128 bits), so now we can operate on 16 bytes at once. And it also supports multiple floating-point operations at once. Then Intel lengthened XMM to the 256-bit YMM in [Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), and doubled the length once again in [AVX-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) (this time it also increased the number of registers to 32 in 64-bit mode). Now you can work on **sixteen 32-bit integers** at a time

From the above you might understand the second and most important role of those registers: **doing operations on multiple data in parallel with a single instruction**. For example in [SSE4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#SSE4.2) a set of [instructions to work on C strings](https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2) have been introduced. Now you can count string length, find sub-strings... much faster by checking multiple bytes at once. You can also copy or compare memory a lot faster. Modern `memcpy` implementations move 16, 32 or 64 bytes at a time depending on the largest register width instead of one-by-one as in the simplest C solution.

Unfortunately the compilers are still bad at converting from scalar code into parallel code so most of the times we have to help them, although auto-vectorization is still getting better and smarter

- [Automatic vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization)
- [Auto-Parallelization and Auto-Vectorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Due to the importance of SIMD, pretty much any high performance architectures nowadays have their own versions of SIMD, like [Altivec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) on PowerPC, [V extension](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec) on RISC-V or [Neon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Advanced_SIMD_(NEON))/[SVE](https://community.arm.com/arm-research/b/articles/posts/the-arm-scalable-vector-extension-sve) on ARM.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some examples:

- [Is SSE floating-point arithmetic reproducible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15147174/995714)
- [Extended (80-bit) double floating point in x87, not SSE2 - we don't miss it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3206101/995714)
- [acos(double) gives different result on x64 and x32 Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45734549/995714)
- [Why would the same code yield different numeric results on 32 vs 64-bit machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7847274/995714)
- [Difference in floating point arithmetics between x86 and x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710272/995714)
- [std::pow produce different result in 32 bit and 64 bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33887108/995714)
- [Why does Math.Exp give different results between 32-bit and 64-bit, with same input, same hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018895/995714)

Comment: It's a bit unfair that you compare x87 code with loads to SSE code without. A calling convention passing floating point arguments in x87 registers is not unthinkable.

Comment: I just want to demonstrate the different instructions that were used like faddp, fmul vs addss, mulss. It's not about the memory load

Comment: Then why do you include a memory load? Façetously, this looks like you want to demonstrate how many more instructions you need to compute this using the x87 FPU when that's actually not really the case.

Comment: I just copy the compiler output. Who said that those was written by me? I just want a simple example with different instructions and different registers since the OP said that he never saw those when disassembling high level code and there they are

Comment: @phuciv I can see that, but the point you are trying to make (that x87 registers are slower) is just not true; for example, on Sandy Bridge the latencies and throughputs of x87 floating point instructions are exactly equal to the figures for SSE instructions.

Comment: @phuclv , so far i have heard of single precision, double precision and quad precision. but i've never heard of oct precision (depends on what you call it) or larger. so for what
 EXACT purpose do the 256 bit and 512 bit registers serve? (i understand the 80 bit and 128 bit registers for 10 byte and 16 byte float operations).

Comment: @user135142 did you read my answer? I already said that they're not for doing 256 or 512-bit math but for operations on multiple 8/16/32/64-bit values at the same time. And no, there's no 16-byte float type in any current SIMD ISAs so no quad-precision math either

Comment: so those large registers are not for large float operations, right?

Comment: @user135142 right. I said it's neither for large float nor large integer operations. Read the links in my answer, most importantly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD for more information. Put it simply they're for parallelization

Comment: @phuclv , what do you mean by parallelization?

Comment: @user135142 it means doing multiple things in parallel. Please spend time reading everything I wrote before asking

Comment: but how come 32 byte numbers are used for multitasking?

Answer (score 4):

These registers are part of the SSE, AVX, and AVX512 instruction set extensions.  Your C compiler should at least use the lower 64 bit of them for floating operations as such is specified in the ABI.

These registers are SIMD (single instruction multiple data) registers mainly used for high performance code.  The processor supports special SIMD instructions that can process multiple data at the same time, taking as much time as normally needed to process a single datum.  Most code using these registers is written in assembly or using special *intrinsic functions* because compilers are quite bad at using SIMD instructions on their own.  Making compilers better at this (an optimization called *auto vectorization*) is an active field of research.

As an example, suppose a program wants to do a matrix multiplication of double precision floating point numbers.  With AVX register `ymm0` to `ymm15`, 4 numbers can be processed at a time, speeding up the algorithm by a factor of 4 compared to a normal implementation. That's quite a difference.

Refer to the instruction set reference for instructions using these registers.  [This website](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) lists all of them in an accessible fashion.  If you want to use them, I suggest you to go with the intrinsic functions as they are a bit easier to use than assembly.