# Add floating point in instruction in x86-64 with general purpose register

Tags: assembly, floating-point, sse, cpu-registers, instruction-set

This tutorial (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions) is just work in integer, doesn't work in double-precision floating point.

It said I must use `xmm` register with `addsd` instruction. Actually yes it's working fine I was using it.

```
addsd xmm0, xmm1
```

But can I have same rule like that tutorial I mean with using general purpose like `rax` and this rule:

- Register to register
- Memory to register
- Register to memory
- Register to constant data
- Memory to constant data

Also why `xmm` register is 128-bit while double-precision floating point is 64-bit. Is another bit wasted?

Comment: SSE registers `xmm0` to `xmm15` are 128 bit, but if you use the “scalar single” or “scalar double” (`ss` or `sd`) variants of floating point instructions, only the low 32 or 64 bit are changed.  As for “rules,” I don't quite understand what you mean.  Check the instruction set reference for details on what operands each instruction you want to use supports.

Comment: What i mean "rules" is operand rules, like I can use immediate value like this ```addsd xmm0, 3.14``` my assembler GAS can't recognize it. ```junk.14 after expression```

Comment: Yes, please refer to the instruction set reference for these rules.  The canonical instruction set reference is in the *Intel Software Development Manuals,* vol. 2.  SSE instructions (just like x87 instructions) do not support immediate operands.  You have to place the floating point constant you want into memory and use a memory operand.  If you like, I can write an answer with some more pointers.

Comment: I've found referring to compiler output helpful, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/hE4rGjsPr has some examples as well as links into documentation when you right-click on instructions

Comment: The high 64 bits of XMM registers are not wasted; they're usable for instructions like `addpd xmm0, xmm1` to do two additions with one instruction (with the same performance as `addsd` on Core 2 / K10 and later.)  SSE stands for "Streaming [**SIMD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) Extensions", after all

Comment: As @SamMason says, looking at compiler output can be really helpful for examples of how to do basic stuff on any ISA you're curious about, including x86-64.  Like `double f(double x){ return x + 1.25; }`, or adding integer variables to float using `cvtsi2sd` for conversion.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more about looking at compiler output, including Matt Godbolt's talk.

Comment: there are no bits wasted. The xmm/ymm/zmm registers are for SIMD: [What are the 128-bit to 512-bit registers used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52932539/995714)